# Javascript object property detection

Tags: javascript

What is the least amount of code needed to do the following:

If an object exists and it has a required property and the property is not an empty string then set a variable to the value of the property else set the variable to a default string.

Assuming that the object variable can only be undefined or a valid object, it can never be a function, null, string or anything else. Also if the object has the required property it is a string and never anything else.

A solution to this maybe:

```
// obj is the object we are testing, prop is the name of the property, def is the default string

var result = def;
if (obj && obj[prop] && obj[prop].length) {
    result = obj[prop];
}
```

Whether this is completely correct I am unsure.

But is there a shorter way?

Thanks,

AJ

Comment: This is how I would do it. It's readable and does what you intend.

Comment: Since this question about looking to optimize working code, i've flagged it for migration to [CodeReview.SE].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to shorten it, you can write:

```
result = (obj && obj[prop]) || def;
```

An empty string is falsy, so you don't need to check the length explicitly.

```
result = <val> || <default>;
```

is a common idiom for setting a variable to a value, with a default if the value is null.

Comment: I didn't know that an empty string was falsy, that is actually very helpful. Thanks